# Issue with install and setup mongodb into m1 macbook

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, installation, laravel-valet

I have an issue with connecting php(valet) and MongoDB. I tried to install MongoDB with pecl and command `sudo pecl install mongodb` and `brew install mongodb` and all time I get some errors during the install process:

`In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/Cursor.c:18: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.17/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:151:4: error: unknown type name 'pcre_cache_entry' pcre_cache_entry *pce; ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [src/MongoDB/Cursor.lo] Error 1 ERROR:` make' failed`.

But when I run `mongo --version` I get:
[image]
and I install MongoDB Compass and as you can see, I can connect to the database and write into it:
[image]
But when I try out to install laravel package `jenssegers/mongodb` I get these errors:[image] I tried with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb` flag but then it install package but it didn't work, I get this error: `Error: Class "MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I find out a great package that helps me in this! [This repo saves me a ton of time and debugging](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions)! Thank you shivammathur!

Answer (score 0):

Hey I also had the same problem. A good alternative is to also follow with this article if you want to stick with `pecl` https://freek.dev/2151-fixing-the-dreaded-pcre2h-file-not-found-error-when-installing-imagick

Comment: Tnx @Giannis for sharing, I didn't find that article while pending hours in debugging :) TNX!